# Excel - Create graph with data from 100 sheets - macro and loop?

Tags: vba, excel, loops, graph

I have a data set with individual measurements of over 100 pieces - each in a single sheet.

I need to create line chart with all data plotted in a single graph.

The name of each sheet is in cell F2

Y-Axis range is E2:E301

X-Axis range is A2:A301

How can I create a marco which automatically plots all data in one graph?
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you record a Macro to create one chart, and then take the code that the Recorder generates, and pop it into this loop, which loops through all Worksheets in your Workbook.

Option Explicit

```
Sub test()

    Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.Name <> "Sheet1" Then

            ' YOUR RECORDED MACRO

        End If
    Next ws

End Sub
```